# How can I convert string to unicode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, unicode-string

I have my one text

```
Japanese:  このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください
```

I have its unicode conversion

```
Unicode:  3053306e004f0054005030924f7f752830573066005100750069006b30c930e930a430d6306b30ed30b030a430f33057307e3059300200203053306e004f0054005030928ab030683082517167093057306a30443067304f306030553044
```

This is I have done with some online tool. Now I need to do same thing using **nodejs**.

So my question is what is that type of Unicode? How can I convert it my Japanese text to unicode?

Comment: `"このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください".split("").map(codepoint => codepoint.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).join("");` and yes, in this case, `split` is exactly what you want, because it splits by codepoints, and not graphemes.

Comment: It's the unicode code points of your string in base16

Comment: @ASDFGerte Well You can answer it as well

Comment: There already is an adequate answer, saving me the effort to write one, thanks :)

Comment: What do you want to do and why? To convert Unicode characters to  numbers you have to use an encoding method like UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 etc. Number values and number of bytes per character differ between encoding schemes so knowing the encoding used is needed to reverse the process. So what is the design objective here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

• `.split("")` — separate string into array from each character // ["こ", "の", "O" ...]

• loop into array with `map()` and replace each character with charCode, converted to `hex` string.

```js
let str = "このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください";

str = str.split("").map( char => addZeros( char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) ) ).join("");

function addZeros(str){ return ("0000" + str).slice(-4) }


console.log( str );

// for comparison
console.log( "3053306e004f0054005030924f7f752830573066005100750069006b30c930e930a430d6306b30ed30b030a430f33057307e3059300200203053306e004f0054005030928ab030683082517167093057306a30443067304f306030553044" )
```

Comment: Thank you... Why `addZero`?

Comment: You should look at [String.prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), it already does the job of your utility function.

Comment: I've noticed, that it adds zeroes, if the hex code has less characters)  To get exactly 4-digit codes for each char, to be able convert back into japanese)

Comment: you could use `.replace()` to remove the need for changing your data to an array, and then back to a string (`const res = str.replace(/./g, c => c.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0'));`)